# Slicer Using Pivot Table Cache Runtime Error 5

Tags: excel, pivot-table, slicers, vba7

I have a pivot table built through a Data Model by which a folder of data was loaded as connection only. There is a separate macro to complete this process as I am trying to make these monthly reports more dynamic. Additionally, I have created macros to build entire pivot tables with this data and, subsequently, set up connected slicers. However, when clearing all connections to test out these macros, I cannot get only the slicers code to run despite all pivot field names being correct; the pivot table still loads just fine. Does this have to do with Pivot or Slicer Cache? If so, how can I clear it, and would it allow this code to run? Note* all of these macros were created through recording, I have not programmed them, so the below code worked while the past Data Model was connected.

```
'Creating Slicer (where error is located)'
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches.Add2(ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Brand"), _
        "[Data].[Geography]").Slicers.Add ActiveSheet, _
        "[Data].[Geography].[Geography]", "Geography1", 808.2, 598.2, _
        144, 194.25
'Moving to desired location'
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Geography1")).Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Geography1").IncrementLeft -458.4
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Geography1").IncrementTop -751.2
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("Geography1").ScaleHeight 0.627027027, msoFalse, _
        msoScaleFromTopLeft
'Formatting'
ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Geography1").Slicers("Geography 1").Style = _
        "Slicer Style 1"
```

I've tried leaving the "name" argument in Add2 blank (e.g., "", a literal blank space, and no argument at all), but this resulted in no slicers being created at all.